# Deleting Documents from Flutter if conditionals are met

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to add a function so that whenever a button is pressed, it will take my variables and look through all documents in my database. Then when it finds a document that matches the variables, it will delete that item. However, I keep getting an error message that I need a ")" after the (doc). Is there a better way to run through all the items to delete them, or am I doing something wrong with the snapshots/forEach statements?

```
   Object deleteUser() {
// Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
if(name!="" && type!="" && location!="") {
      items.snapshots().forEach(
              (doc) => if(doc.data['name']==deleteName && doc.data['type']==deleteType && doc.data['location']==deleteLocation => doc.delete();));
      return items;
}else{
  return "There was a null error";
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `forEach` loop is what's throwing the error as it isn't valid dart. I cleaned it up, this should work for you.

```
  Object deleteUser() {
    // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
    if (name != "" && type != "" && location != "") {
      for (var doc in items.snapshots()) {
        if (doc.data['name'] == deleteName &&
            doc.data['type'] == deleteType &&
            doc.data['location'] == deleteLocation) {
          doc.delete();
        }
      }
      return items;
    } else {
      return "There was a null error";
    }
  }
```